# Automatic newline in emacs

Tags: emacs, autofill

I would like to configure emacs in such a way that if - while typing - I reach some width size in the buffer, I can get to the next line automatically, with no RET or ...
Actually, I have a problem, that when I copy a text from other source, then a line might be longer than the width size so emacs leverages it on several lines and marks that with (not visually nice) arrows.

Thank you for your help;

Answer (score 8):

To break lines automatically when typing, turn on auto-fill-mode: `M-x auto-fill-mode`

For text that you paste from somewhere else, hit `M-q` (which invokes the command `fill-paragraph`) to break the lines after the fact.